# Loop Through a List of Integers and Reduce Them Until An Amount is Zero

Tags: scala

I have this problem which can be simplified to the following:

Say I have a list of integers like so:

```scala
List(20,30,40,50,90)
```

and a value of x = 100 say.

I want to loop through that list of integers and subtract the first value from 100 and then the second, and so on until x reaches 0.

So in this example I would then be left with

```scala
List(0,0,0,40,90) and x = 0
```

I tried the usual map through the elements of the list but the problem is that x = 100, I don't know how to keep updating that inside the map to get the new reduced value of it after subtracting an element in the list from it.

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this but I am not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: You can, write your own taiñ-recursive method. Use `foldLeft` or use `List.unfold`

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 0 or it can be 0 or less?

Comment: @michaJlS the stopping condition for the looping is when x = 0.

Comment: what if you go below 0?

Comment: just cannot go below zero - it blows up the logic of the program

Comment: @jwvh not sure what you mean. The sum of the list of integers will always be greater than the value of x.

Comment: Never mind. I miss-read the question. Your example made it look like you were subtracting whole list elements from `x`.

Comment: I don't understand the logic at all. Why, if you subtract the first value of the list from 100, you get 0? The first value of the list is 20. 20 subtracted from 100 is 80, not 0. Same for the second value: 30 subtracted from 100 is 70, not 0. Also, what do you mean by "until x reaches 0"? You just said x is 100. 100 is not 0, and x is never changed anywhere, so x will never reach 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments and an alternative to the other answer which uses foldLeft, you can hand-craft your own tail-recursive method:

```scala
def compute(xs: List[Int], x: Int): List[Int] = {

  def loop(cs: List[Int], ns: List[Int], remainder: Int): List[Int] =
    cs match {
      case ::(head, next) =>
        loop(next, ns :+ math.max(head - remainder, 0), math.max(remainder - head, 0))
      case Nil            => ns
    }
  loop(xs, List.empty, x)
}

compute(List(20, 30, 40, 50, 90), 100)
```

Output:

```scala
val res0: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 0, 40, 90)
```

Answer (score 3):

`unfold()` (Scala 2.13.x) offers a rather concise solution.

```
def subtractFromList(x: Int, lst: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  List.unfold((x,lst)){
    case (n,hd::tl) =>
      Some(if (hd > n) (hd-n,(0,tl)) else (0,(n-hd,tl)))
    case _ => None
  }

subtractFromList(8, List(1,3,6,9))          //List(0, 0, 2, 9)
subtractFromList(100, List(20,30,40,50,90)) //List(0, 0, 0, 40, 90)
```

---

Or, the same idea via regular (non-tail) recursion.

```
def subtractFromList(x: Int, lst: List[Int]): List[Int] = lst match {
  case hd::tl => if (hd > x) hd-x :: subtractFromList(0, tl)
                 else           0 :: subtractFromList(x-hd, tl)
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foldLeft`:

```scala
  val result = List(20, 30, 40, 50, 90)
    .foldLeft[(Int, List[Int])](100, Nil)((result, value) =>
      (math.max(0, result._1 - value), result._2 :+ math.max(0, value - result._1))
    )
```

result:

```scala
(0,List(0, 0, 0, 40, 90))
```